# Why jslint restrict number of characters in a line?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, jslint

Some projects I'm working on have a jslint rule that restrict the number of characters in a line(usually is 100 characters). In some situation, it makes my javascript code look so ugly, but I believe they did that for some reasons. So, what are good reasons for applying that rule?

Comment: to keep lines from being too long, where is the value of "long" varies by personal preference, coding standards, etcetera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long lines in general are harder to read. Personally I can go up to 150 characters before reaching the edge of my code editor, but I could get more just by maximizing the window. But someone else might have a smaller screen or window in their environment. Enforcing about 100 as a recommended "don't go over this length" limit accomodates most people's ability to see the entire line of code without horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Another reason I can think of is that they don't want to have many nested loop, condition statement (if, for...) but not sure